# Angular ng-csv after ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple task of downloading an array of objects using ng-csv. The problem with it is that the array i want to download is initially empty and is populated after the ng-click. But on the first click, the csv downloaded is empty and on second click, it downloads the specific data. I want ng-click because i have to pass the index of sheet i want to download.
So basically i want the ng-click event to populate the array first and the 
ng-csv to download the array.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Here is my div

```
  <div ng-csv="getArray" filename="test.csv" field-separator="," ng-click="clickFn($index)"</div>
```

Comment: it should support `ng-csv="getArray($index)"`

Comment: getArray is not a function, its just a scope variable in my js. Also how would my js look like if i use getArray($index) ??

Answer (score 0):

```
myApp.controller('FooController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.getArray = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
  $scope.getArrayData = function(index){
    //filter data with index in getArray and return it;
  };
}]);
```

and in html use,

```
ng-csv="getArrayData($index)"
```

hope this helps.

Comment: `<div ng-csv="getArrayData($index)" filename="test.csv" field-separator="," </div>` you mean like this or ?

So. whatever the getArrayData() returns will be in test.csv file